# Saving a tab separated file in Excel without quotes

Tags: microsoft-excel, textfiles

I have a tab separated value file that I want to edit in Excel. When Excel saves the file it modifies any column with quotes. It puts quotes around the whole column, and then double any quotes within the content of the column ( `"` -> `""` ).

I don't want quotes around my columns and I don't want my quotes within columns escaped. The program that reads this file is not expecting quotes around the columns. Is there anyway to save or export the file without these added quotes?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To save Excel file into tab separated file (without quotes added):

1. In Excel, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to select all
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to copy
3. Open Notepad, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to paste
4. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to save and it is done

Comment: Bloody genius!  Works!  Saved my bacon.  Wilson, how in the world did you learn this??

Comment: Whoops.  Even using this method, Excel still erroneously inserts " at the beginning of cell in column-A if row follows a group.

Comment: @DougNull what does it mean by "row follows a group"?

Comment: If you manually do like this, you might end up with a bad encoding and when you read the same file in python you might get error like 'utf-8 codec can't decode byte.....'

Comment: So simple, and yet so beautiful! @RajarsheeMitra It's funny because I came here trying to solve that exact problem, and copying manually to notepad++ and saving the file from there did the trick!

Answer (score 3):

Find & Replace this: (`"`)
With a null value: ()
Manually.

Then,

Find & Replace 'All' of this (`""`)
With this: (`"`)

Comment: If the Excel file is long, there will be a lot of human work.

Comment: One option can be to replace ("") to a character which won't be there in the tab delimited file like (~) or (^), then to replace " to () and then finally (~) or (^) to (").

Comment: @jhamu, nice improvement to reduce human work :)

Comment: This will end in a catastrophy if your data already contains `"` for example item descriptions like 24" LCD

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility for Excel to do this. I had the same problem and ended up writing a `sed` script to convert it. ([sed is also available for windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm))

```
sed "s/^\"//g;s/\"$//g;s/\t\"/\t/g;s/\"\t/\t/g;s/\"\"/\"/g" -i your-file.txt
```

It basically consists of multiple search&replace tasks `s/search/replace/g` (g=global=replace all). First, it searches for all surrounding quotes and finally replaces all double quotes with a single quote.