# Number format for text export from Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, export

Basically I am exporting a block of columns from Excel to text file.
that might look similar to this in Excel:

> 0 34.3 22.555 56.8970 34

Now I want that to look in the text file as:

> 0.000 34.300 22.555 56.897 34.000

so, essentially keeping the spacing the same (same number of decimals).

But, when I export I am not able to achieve that.

Tips and helps will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you've formatted the cells in Excel to look the way you want them to appear (i.e. in this case: Format, Cells, Number, Decimal places = 3) when you Save As, Text, it should save the text with the appropriate number of decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

1. **Format the cell(s) to the desire format**
   Highlight the cell(s) > Press `Ctrl-1` (or right click, format cells) > Number > Decimal places = 3
2. **Save**
   a) File > Save As > Choose appropriate file format, like CSV <sup>(1)</sup> or TSV <sup>(2)</sup> > Save
   *---OR---*
   b) For TSV <sup>(2)</sup> with no quotes `"`, [Select all > Copy > Open Notepad > Paste > Save](https://superuser.com/questions/206060/saving-a-tab-separated-file-in-excel-without-quotes/)

The decimal places formatting is preserved. (Tested in Excel 2003)

**Note:**
(1) CSV = Comma-separated values file format ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values))
(2) TSV = Tab-separated values file format ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab-separated_values))

Comment: great! that was exactly what i needed. I read Craig's reply and tried to figure that out, but you made it much simpler :)

Comment: @kaushik, glad that my answer is useful :) please accept it if it is the most suitable answer~