# How do I change the delimiter when copy-pasting from Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I would like to copy cells from Excel and paste them into Notepad using the comma `,` as delimiter, instead of the tab character.

Is there any way to change the delimiter without doing a find-and-replace in Notepad or saving the spreadsheet as CSV?

Comment: Refer to my answer in another question: http://superuser.com/questions/206060/saving-a-tab-separated-file-in-excel-without-quotes/206097#206097

Comment: @wilson Stefan is asking about doing it without using Notepad, and to use something other than tab as the delimiter

Comment: @RowlandShaw: Stefan said "without doing a replace in Notepad", not "without Notepad".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's any way of changing the default delimiter character (i.e. Tab) used while copying text to the clipboard from Excel. What you can do however is create a macro to achieve the result you want.

1. [Create a macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814737%28v=office.14%29.aspx) named something like **CopySelectedCells** and optionally assign a keyboard shortcut so you can invoke it quickly (I assigned it <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> for example):

   [image: 1]
2. From the main **Macro** dialog shown above, click the **Edit** button to open the VBA Editor.
3. Go to `Tools menu / References` and click on the **Browse** button.
4. Add **Windows\System32\FM20.dll**:

   [image: 2]
5. Select the **Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library** option now added to the **Available References** list:

   [image: 3]
6. Edit the macro code to look like the following:

   ```
   Sub CopySelectedCells()
       Dim str As String
       For Each rangeRow In Selection.Rows
           For Each rangeCol In rangeRow.Cells
               str = str & rangeCol.Value & ","
           Next
           str = Left(str, Len(str) - 1) & vbCrLf
       Next

       With New DataObject
           .SetText str
           .PutInClipboard
       End With
   End Sub
   ```
7. Close the VBA Editor, select a range of cells and invoke the macro, then paste in Notepad to see the comma-separated result.

Answer (score 0):

Contatenate required cells as string in a not used cell with comma between them and copy only this new cell and paste in notepad.
For example: =A1&","&B1

Comment: If there are hundreds of columns then `concatenate` may not be a good option as you have to select cells by hand and cannot drag-select the cells to be concatenated.

Answer (score -2):

You could replace all tabs with commas in Notepad++. Select all text, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> and use `\t` for tab. Be sure to turn "Extended" search mode on.

[image: Replace tabs with commas]

Comment: How is this any better compared to replacing Tabs in Notepad?

Comment: It's a significant improvement because it doesn't use notepad :)