# Copy from Excel without Line Break

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I copy text from a cell in Excel and paste into a text document a line break is appended.

Example:

```
<a href="#">Some Link</a>
```

CTRL-C/CTRL-V

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com
">Some Link</a>
```

Is it possible to copy as plain text without additional line breaks added?

Comment: Can't you press F2 and copy the cell's contents?

Comment: F2 edits a cell

Comment: What Karan means is, that you press F2 → Select the cell content with your arrow keys → copy&paste it with CTRL+C and CTRL+V

Comment: Ah I understand.  That does work.  If one of you posts as an answer I'll accept it.  Thank you!

Comment: An [equivalent question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14695836/145173) on StackOverflow has a macro-based answers that minimizes keystrokes.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> > <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> >  <kbd>Backspace</kbd> is probably better than the accepted answer due to fewer key strokes. I know this doesn't really answer the question, it sounds like your question is really a feature request. As mentioned in the comments here is a macro solution as well:

https://stackoverflow.com/q/14695836/145173

Sounds like too much work to me to avoid a backspace key stroke. If it's large grabs and pulls, I would just suggest using Notepad++'s advanced find/replace and exploit the `\n\r\t` characters that are the real text appended to the copy/paste and replace them with nothing.

Answer (score 11):

Simply press <kbd>F2</kbd> to edit the cell, select all text (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> ought to do it, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> for multi-line cell), then copy (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and paste (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) without line breaks being added.

Comment: BTW, here's a [macro](http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/391131-can-you-copy-an-excel-cell-without-the-automatic-line-break.html) and [AHK script](http://www.autohotkey.com/board/topic/62759-remove-linebreak-after-copying-excel/) if you want to do this for lots of cells and want to make things easier. See [here](http://superuser.com/a/507136/138343) if you want help with adding a reference to the **Microsoft Forms 2.0 Object Library** required to make that macro work.

Comment: This method doesn't work if the cell contains a formula and you want to copy the computed value.

Comment: This answers the question at the cost of added keystrokes compared to simple backspace answer below.. not really a good solution

Comment: What an idea stands behind the scenes to add new line to content being copied??? !!!!