# Can I copy a cell contents to paste into a text-editor without a line-break?

Tags: microsoft-excel

If you select a cell in Excel containing text or a numeric value and copy to clipboard, then paste into an application like Notepad or Word, it always pastes a line-break.

[image]
[image]
[image]

If you double-click the cell and select-all the contents in edit mode, you can copy-paste this but thats quite cumbersome as you now can't use only the keyboard, and it adds extra clicks.

I wondered if there might be a special keyboard shortcut to copy as if I was editing the cell contents?

Comment: Could you edit your post and include some screenshots of what you would select and copy and what you would like to see in the pasted data in the document? There are some options for you, but it will help if you can show the expected result.

Comment: @Owen sure but you can test by opening any spreadsheet and copying a cell into notepad...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Copy from Excel without Line Break](https://superuser.com/questions/543615/copy-from-excel-without-line-break)

Comment: Thanks.  Wasn't sure whether you were trying to copy one cell or more. Actually after thinking about it, I realised it wouldn't matter. What I was going to suggest wouldn't have helped anyway!

Comment: @Owen seems like the same question. Shame there's not a "edit and select" shortcut :)

Answer (score 0):

Double click on the desired cell (rather than just single clicking/selecting it), hit ctrl + a to copy the contents, and paste it

Comment: Was it? The original post was like two sentences, now it's heavily edited with lots added to it....

Comment: Yes. Check the edit history...

Comment: Yea all it says is that you deleted some text, but doesn't reference other stuff you've added like the pictures that someone requested correct?

Answer (score 0):

select cell press `F2` then `Shift + Home` and then `Ctrl + c` 
and paste  to the destination