# how do i just copy excel to txt with space and '\n' as delimiter

Tags: microsoft-excel

When I copy excel to txt, the I can't get the delimiter for different columns as space, ' ' and the delimiter for different rows as '\n'. Is there someway for me achieve that? Because I am building a c++ program to read from such txt file....  Thank you.

Comment: Do you mind explaining why you can't work with the default tab column delimiter?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the delimiter when you copy from Excel and paste to notepad](http://superuser.com/questions/506470/how-to-change-the-delimiter-when-you-copy-from-excel-and-paste-to-notepad). Same question, just a different delimiter. All you need to do in [my macro](http://superuser.com/a/507136/138343) is replace the comma with a space.

Comment: @Excellll, the reason is that in our practice of c++ programming, we tried to avoid tab and only use spaces....

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using just copying the content from Excel and pasting into a text document, you should use the builtin "Export" functionality in Excel. That way you can ensure the delimiter and EOL as you want.

You need to act by using "Save as" of File menu.
Details can be found here: https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Import-or-export-text-txt-or-csv-files-5250ac4c-663c-47ce-937b-339e391393ba#bmexport